# Fowarding IP Traffic without NAT (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I've been setting up OpenVPN and all the standard guides I have been following suggest setting up `iptables` so that the VPN server performs NAT on the VPN clients:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s *vpn-ip-range* -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

This works great. However, because of the NAT all the logging on our other internal machines reports the traffic coming from the VPN server IP and not the client IP.

I would like to remove the NAT and have the client IP used throughout the network (for audit purposes). I've already done the following:

- Update OpenVPN configuration to supply internal IP addresses to all clients (subnet of `10.0.0.0/8`)
- Add a static route to our main gateway to route this subnet to the IP address of the VPN server

The final step is updating `iptables`. This is where I can't seem to get it to work.

The network card is `eth0` and all OpenVPN traffic is on `tun0`. All I want to do is for the VPN server to forward traffic between these interfaces when related to `10.0.0.0/8` traffic.

Can anyone suggest how I would do this?

Comment: You don't need any iptables on your OpenVPN server. Just those routes (if you go the tun way):
https://superuser.com/questions/1093482/port-forward-from-lan-to-an-openvpn-client-iptables/1093504#1093504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out. Although I had already added `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (which most guides point out), I also need to add `net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1`.

The `iptables` configuration then just needs to allow all traffic on both interfaces and it works!

Answer (score 0):

A quick turnaround way for this could be modifying how logging is working to make it record $http_x_forwarded_for values which will then log actual client IP.

Not sure weather you will be able to modify how your logging is happening but i hope this helps.